# write pseudocode to delete the specificed integer on the array

Tags: pseudocode

Please explain us the logic behind this program. I am really clueless on where to start, so please be as simple as possible.

```
Loop x from 0 to 9
if n[5]=50
do not print
End loop
```

Suppose, I want to delete 5th element from the array, such that all elements after that each ascend one position; 6th becomes the 5th, 7th becomes the 6th. How do I do this?

Comment: Where did you get this pseudocode from? I don't even understand it myself. What does "do not print" mean?

Comment: I've somehow answered your question. But you need to give more details, in-order for us to answer more accurately other than just guess the missing info.

Answer (score 0):

*From what I've understand from your question.* It loops using the variable X, from counter 0~9. 
Then prints it's values, but if the value of n[5] (array with index of 5) is equal to 50 then it won't print it's value.

pseudo code

```
while(X <= 9)
{
   if(x != 5 && n[5] != 50)
   {
      print n[x];
   }
   X++;
}
```